# Android Start Ellipsis only supported with one line

Tags: textview, android, ellipsis

I want to have `...` at the beginning of a single-line text view..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialer_display_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dialer_display_number_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:maxLength="31"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

However, it doesn't work and shows warning message

> W/StaticLayout﹕ Start Ellipsis only supported with one line

I notice that if I remove singleLine="true", the warning will not appear.. but in any way, long text is not shortened with `...` at the beginning

Comment: use android:lines = "2"

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash do I still use singleLine="true"? I set android:lines="1" it has no effect. I don't want two lines.

Comment: no remove singleLine="true"

Comment: I replaced singleLine with ```android:lines="1"``` it has no effect. I don't want two lines

Comment: @xialin Try out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the property `android:maxLength="31"` from your `TextView` and check. As you have already defined the length of your `TextView` so it will filter your text for the given input.

Answer (score 0):

remove android:maxLength="31"
and add android:maxEms="31".

it will solve your bug without any side-effects and changes.